# USB Power Saving Settings

Tags: usb, power-management, lock-screen, screensaver

I have a USB weather station.  If the screensaver kicks on (blank screen and lock), data from the weather station stalls out.  I can lock the screen manually and I have no issues at all with the weather station data stalling out.  If I run lsusb, the weather station is listed as...

```
Bus 013 Device 004: ID 1941:8021 Dream Link WH1080 Weather Station / USB Missile Launcher
```

Could I go to /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb13/power (assuming that is the correct location for the weather station) and edit the files to prevent data from stalling out when Ubuntu kicks on the screensaver?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Editing like "using `gedit` or `nano` to change the values":

## No

***But:*** `echo 0 >/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb13/power`

## Yes! ;-)

(do a `cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb13/manufacturer` and/or cat `/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb13/product` to be absolutely sure that you're changing the right one!)